# No se pueden abrir los archivos después de subirlos a una carpeta de mi proyecto con jquery ajax en asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hola amigos espero puedan ayudarme con este problema no se porque sucede ya que los archivos se suben correctamente a una carpeta de mi proyecto pero al abrirlos estos marcan error espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias. Estoy trabajando con jquery ajax y asp.net c# webForms.

```
// Mensaje de error al abrir el archivo

Excel no se puede abrir el archivo 'Prueba.xlsx' porque el formato o la extension de este no son validos. Compruebe que el archivo no se ha dañado y que la extension del mismo coincide con el formato del archivo.
```

Aquí coloco mi código html y javascript.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">      

        $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
            var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
            $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
        });

        $('#btnUploadFile').click(function() {
            if ($('#fileupload').val() == '') {
                alert('selecciona archivo');
                return;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Prueba.aspx/GuardarExcel",
                data: "{'filename' : " + JSON.stringify($("#fileupload").val()) + "}",
                //async: true,                
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data, status) {
                    console.log($("#fileupload").val());
                    alert(data.d);
                    alert("Archivo guardado");
                },
                failure: function(data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }

            });

        });
        
        
    </script>
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">  
                      
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" class="custom-file-input"  />
                    <label id="lblArchivo" class="custom-file-label" for="fileupload">seleccione archivo</label>
                </div> 
                              
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
             <button type="button" id="btnUploadFile" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
```

Aquí coloco mi WebMethod

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GuardarExcel(string filename)
    {

        string nombre_archivo = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        string location = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Archivos_Subidos/" + nombre_archivo);
        HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs(location, false);

        string dato = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nombre_archivo, Formatting.None);
        return nombre_archivo;


}
```

Como he mencionado anteriormente el código no me marca error y los archivos son subidos a la carpeta correctamente pero al abrirlos estos mandan el mensaje de error y no puedo visualizar su contenido.

Comment: Has probado a cambiar la extensión `.xlsx` por `.xls`?

Answer (score -1):

Se me ocurre que estés escribiendo los ficheros en el sistema de archivos con una serie de permisos que impiden abrir los mismos después?

Hay un post similar en el que se hace referencia a establecer los permisos de carpetas y ficheros que tal vez pueda ayudarte?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266934/how-to-set-folder-permissions-with-net

Salu2.